# JQGrid Row Editing

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a jqgrid with edit and delete button on each row , when I click on edit button it goes to my edit function in controller we are good till here but when I click on delete button as well it goes to my edit function instead of delete [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQqV3.png)function any help is appriciated.

[image]

Comment: Please see the image for the code that I have

Comment: Please copy the code instead of posting the image. Additionally you should always write which **the version** of jqGrid, which you use (can use), and from which **the fork** of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7)

Answer (score 0):

Main error in your current code: the usage of wrong value for `delOptions` of `formatoptions` of the `formatter: "actions"`. The correct value should be **object** in format required by `delGridRow` method. For example, you can use

```
{
    name: "actions", formatter: "actions", align: "center", frozen: true,
    fixed: true, hidedlg: true, resizable: false, sortable: false,
    search: false, editable: false, viewable: false,
    width: 100,
    formatoptions: {
        key: true,
        delOptions: {
            url: "/GridRowEditWithPics/deleteGridData"
        }
    }
}
```